# Custom Field is not working in Contact Form 7 in ver 4.1.1

Tags: wordpress, forms, custom-fields, contact-form-7

There was a situation where i had to create a custom hidden field in Contact Form 7 which captures page url. I used following code to achieve it.

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_init', 'wpcf7_add_shortcode_sourceurl' );
wpcf7_add_shortcode('sourceurl', 'wpcf7_sourceurl_shortcode_handler', true);

function wpcf7_sourceurl_shortcode_handler($tag) {
if (!is_array($tag)) return '';

$name = $tag['name'];
if (empty($name)) return '';

$html = '<input type="hidden" name="' . $name . '" value="http://' .$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] . '" />';
return $html;
}
```

It was working fine till i upgraded my Contact Form 7 to version 4.1.1

Any body can help to so that i can acheive the same in latest version of Contact Form 7 4.1.1 or 4.1.2.

Thank you,

~Waseem~

I

Comment: you upgrade plugin or wordpress and where you add this code

Comment: I upgraded plugin. I had created a new sourceurl.php file and saved it on modules folder of Contact Form 7 plugin.

Comment: first never never never edit the plugin or wordpress core files ... because when we upgrade plugin or wordpress the files overwrite on old files and if we write code on those files will be deleted ... so add these types of codes (hooks and filters) always in theme's functions.php ... use this code in functions.php again and see what happen

Answer (score 1):

try to upload this plugin [wpcf7 field extend](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-modules/installation/)